# FadeIn stuck in jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, hide, fadein

When I use this code

```
$("#mainMenu .home").hover(
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").fadeIn("fast");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").css("background-position", "440px 600px");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").text("Naslovna");
  },
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").hide();
  }
);
$("#mainMenu .alarm").hover(
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").fadeIn("fast");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").css("background-position", "440px 583px");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").text("Alarm (9)");
  },
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").hide();
  }
);
```

and move quickly with the mouse through the menu it gets stuck. How to do that is properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `.stop()` before any animation to cancel the current animation.

```
$("#mainMenu .home").hover(
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").stop().fadeIn("fast");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").css("background-position", "440px 600px");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").text("Naslovna");
  },
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").stop().hide();
  }
);
$("#mainMenu .alarm").hover(
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").stop().fadeIn("fast");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").css("background-position", "440px 583px");
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").text("Alarm (9)");
  },
  function () {
      $("#mainMenuHoverTitle").stop().hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: when i use this code and fast move over the menu next time hover doesn't appear

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I used jqery 1.7.1 and now I changed to 1.10.2 and now works great! Thanks a lot

Comment: Solved my issue with `fadeTo()`! Thanks!